# Trying to find method to force this MDL button to go to the link in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design, material-design-lite

I'm using this MDL button:

```
<div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
  <a class=
  "mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent"
  href="www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
</div>
```

When you click it, it will go to the link within the same tab in the web browser. I want the link to be forced to open a new tab. I understand you can do this using things such as angular.js, some other scripting language or calling the windows service on the page. I wanted to expand my knowledge and see if there were any simpler ways towards executing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Stack Overflow</a>`

`target="_blank"` will make a link open in a new tab.

Comment: Thank you very much! Have a great day.